# Setting VM flags failed

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I have added flutter to intellij but when i run the code this error appear[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zfxd.png)

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem with IntelliJ. To fix this move to the box beside the run button then click on it, select edit configurations, then disable the Checked mode below VM options then click on Ok.