# globals.platform.environment['LOCALAPPDATA'] / FVM / Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, fvm

When I run `fvm flutter doctor` in VSCode, I get this error:

```
Building flutter tool...
../../../../../../fvm/versions/1.22.6/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/android_studio.dart:379:37: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
        globals.platform.environment['LOCALAPPDATA'],
```

In Android Studio with the same command I get:

```
Building flutter tool...
Setting VM flags failed: Unrecognized flags: verbosity
```

I don't know how to fix this. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

[According this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57021221/setting-vm-flags-failed):

I was having the same problem with IntelliJ. To fix this move to the box beside the run button then click on it, select edit configurations, then disable the Checked mode below VM options then click on Ok.

or you can see this [page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35594):